# How do you install a package from Github in Docker for an R Shiny App?

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I put together a [Shiny App](https://github.com/benyamindsmith/starBlissGUI). That makes use of [a package that I authored](https://github.com/benyamindsmith/starBliss) but have had no success with being able to successfully build a docker image that works.

The code I am using presently is:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.2.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libxml2-dev

RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("shiny","shinyWidgets","ggplot2","lubridate", "remotes"))'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("benyamindsmith/starBliss")'

COPY app.R /app/
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app')"]
```

Which does successfully build. However, when I run the image, I get the following message:

```
Error in library(starBliss) : there is no package called ‘starBliss’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
Execution halted
```

I've done some looking around but have not successfully figured out why the built image doesn't recognize the `starBliss` package which it successfully installed during the build.

How do I install a repository from Github in a docker image so that it is recognized during runtime?

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't build for me. Could you try adding the following libs to ``apt-get``: ``libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev``

Answer (score 1):

Using the advice from @runr and after doing some Googling, here is the script that currently works:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libgdal-dev

RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("shiny","shinyWidgets","ggplot2","lubridate", "remotes"))'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("benyamindsmith/starBliss")'

COPY app.R /srv/shiny-server/
COPY www /srv/shiny-server/www

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/',, host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]
```